# Export svn to git without a folder

Tags: git, git-svn

I would like to migrate svn solution but without a specified files/folder.

My problem is such because I commited a big library (50 mb) into svn which I do not need now, and I do not need project which use it. But the rest of solution is still important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is easier in git.  So I'd get out of Subversion as quickly as I could.  For example, you could use [git2svn](https://github.com/etgryphon/git2svn) to move your solution to git.

Once you're in git, you can remove files per the [Github Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) guide.  It uses `filter-branch` to permanently purge a file from the git repository.